# Restoring Clipped Sinusoidal Data

Tags: fft, clipping

I have an 1D array of sinusoidal data. The upper part of the data are clipped as shown in the image. [Clipped signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlUH2.png)
Now I think that the actual sinusoidal signal can be obtained by taking fft of the clipped signal and only keeping the frequency of the sinusoidal signal. But the problem with the sinusoidal signal is that it has a discontinuity. This discontinuity needs to be present in the recovered signal as well. If I take fft of this clipped signal, there will be frequency components due to the discontinuity which needs to be preserved. So, I can't only choose the frequency peaks for the sinusoidal part. The actual data should look as follows, [Original signal that I expect to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNDcO.png)

I want to know if there is any way to obtain the original signal from the clipped signal without using fft.

When I take fft of the data and choose the peaks for the sinusoidal signal, I lose the discontinuous abrupt part of the data which needs to be kept in the original data.

Comment: This is more of a DSP question than an actual programming question - you'll be more likely to get answers on the DSP StackExchange: https://dsp.stackexchange.com